# How to call route resource which is inside route group with prefix?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-blade

I create a route resource which is inside in route group. But when I call this resource route in blade template it's show me Route not defined. What should I do. I am using Laravel 5.5.
My Route is..

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    Route::get('dashboard', ['as' => 'dashboardRoute', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@index']);
    Route::resource('categories', 'CategoryController');
});
```

My blade view is..

```
<div id="2" class="collapse">
        <a href="{{ route('admin.categories.index') }}" class="list-group-item small">Category</a>
    </div>
```

Error is..

> Route [admin.categories.index] not defined. (View: D:\XAMPPP\htdocs\dynamic_blog\resources\views\admin\sidebar.blade.php) (View: D:\XAMPPP\htdocs\dynamic_blog\resources\views\admin\sidebar.blade.php) (View: D:\XAMPPP\htdocs\dynamic_blog\resources\views\admin\sidebar.blade.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `as` index to the route group, that should prefix it with `admin.`

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth', 'as' => 'admin.'], function(){
    Route::get('dashboard', ['as' => 'dashboardRoute', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@index']);
    Route::resource('categories', 'CategoryController');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your routes are most likely cached.

Run

> php artisan route:clear

to clear the route cache.

Comment: still not works.
error: throw new InvalidArgumentException("Route [{$name}] not defined.");

Comment: This is a different error, if `$name` contains the string of the route you will probably need to echo it using the `{{ }}` blade operator (note that we are using 2 brackets instead of 1).

Comment: I don't understand. would you please give an example. It works {{ url('admin/categories') }} but {{ route ('admin.categories.index') not working.